# How to create triple Venn diagram with proportional size

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to plot a triple Venn diagram but it's not size proportional.
Below is the code. Is it possible to make it size proportional?

```r
library(VennDiagram)

grid.newpage()
draw.triple.venn(area1=2125, area2=805, area3=387, 
                 n12=805, n23=385, n13=387, n123=385, 
                 category=c("All Extractables","CERAPP","ToxCast"),
                 col="Black",fill=c("White","Red","Yellow"),
                 cex = 3, 
                 cat.cex = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want the circles scaled depending on their contained values (so, for example, circle one will be <sup>2125</sup>/<sub>805</sub> the size of circle 2), I think you have to pass in both `euler.d` and `scaled` as `TRUE` when making the call. And, since scaling is usually disabled due to the potential of misleading diagrams, you have to set `overrideTriple` to some value to allow this.

So, running the code below (suitable for running with `rscript` and to give me enough time to capture the output):

```r
library(grid)
library(VennDiagram)

windows()
grid.newpage()
overrideTriple = TRUE
draw.triple.venn(
    area1=200, area2=300, area3=400, n12=20, n23=30, n13=40, n123=10, 
    category=c("#1","#2","#3"),
    col="Black",fill=c("White","Red","Yellow"),
    cex=3, cat.cex=2, euler.d=TRUE, scaled=TRUE)
Sys.sleep(20)
```

will give you:

[image]

---

However, in regard to your comment about *specific* values not sizing correctly, the code you gave was (again, set up for `rscript` and capture):

```r
library(grid)
library(VennDiagram)

windows()
grid.newpage()
overrideTriple = TRUE
draw.triple.venn(
    area1=2125, area2=805, area3=387,
    n12=805, n23=385, n13=387,
    n123=385, 
    category=c("#1","#2","#3"), 
    col="Black",fill=c("White","Red","Yellow"),
    cex=3, cat.cex=2,
    euler.d=TRUE, scaled=TRUE)
Sys.sleep(20)
```

This generated:

[image]

In this rendering, collections #2 and #3 are rightly *inside* #1 as they're wholly contained values (`area2 == n12` and `area3 == n13`). #1 is clearly bigger in the diagram but that may be an artefact of showing containment rather than actual sizing based on value.

What *is* clear the that #2 and #3 are rendered at the same size despite the fact one should be about double the size of the other. So you are correct that these values do not work. The documentation contains this little snippet but no further elaboration on the special cases is given.

> Euler diagrams are drawn for 19 special cases if `euler.d == TRUE`.

If you think about it, some situations are clearly impossible to render with circles. Consider if the union of #2 and #3 was the entirety of #1 (i.e., there were no items that were "just #1"). There is no way that two smaller circles wholly contained within a larger circle could have the same area as the larger (though rectangles would probably work for that case).

There are other cases as well, such as an outer collection of 1000 containing two inner collections of 500 and 499, with no overlap between the inner collections.

Since `diameter = 2√(area/π)`, the two inner circles would then each have a diameter of about 25 units and the outer circle would be about 36 units. It's been a while since I did geometry but I'm struggling trying to figure out how you could put both those inner circles within the outer circle without *some* overlap :-)

---

Digging deeper, we can go and examine the actual *code* of `VennDiagram`. The section for deciding these special cases can be found in [`decide.special.case.R`](https://github.com/cran/VennDiagram/blob/master/R/decide.special.case.R), which is called from [`draw.triple.venn.R`](https://github.com/cran/VennDiagram/blob/master/R/draw.triple.venn.R).

The latter is where it selects one of `draw.sp.case.scaled` or `draw.sp.case.preprocess` as the function to call, based on the special case found. The 19 special cases are, with a decision as to whether they scale or preprocess (noting that other cases neither scale nor preprocess):

- `022AAAO`, `022AAOO`, `023`, `032`, `120`, `121AO`, `122AAOO`, and `130` will scale.
- `100`, `033`, `011A`, `021AA`, `011O`, `112AA`, `010`, `110`, `001`, `012AA`, and `111A` will not scale.

The first three digits are important here, they are (from the comments):

- First digit is how many triple overlaps are missing (0-1).
- Second digit is how many double overlaps are missing (0-3).
- Third digit is how many distinct (non-overlap) sections are missing (0-3).

The code for figuring this out is a little complicated. The `a1..a7` variables used align with the values in the following (ideal) graphic. For example `1` in the graphic represents `a1`, the stuff in #1 that is not in any of the overlaps:

[image]

In your data, these *actual* values are set as follows, the letters on the right indicate whether it's (n) a non-overlap area, (d) a double overlap area, or (t) a triple overlap area:

```r
a1 <- area1 - n12 - n13 + n123; # 2125 - 805 - 387 - 385 = 548 n
a3 <- area2 - n12 - n23 + n123; #  805 - 805 - 385 + 385 =   0 n
a7 <- area3 - n13 - n23 + n123; #  387 - 387 - 385 + 385 =   0 n

a2 <- n12 - n123;               #  805 - 385             = 420 d
a4 <- n13 - n123;               #  387 - 385             =   2 d
a6 <- n23 - n123;               #  385 - 385             =   0 d

a5 <- n123;                     #  385                   = 385 t
```

You can see by those values that you have no missing triple overlaps, one missing double overlap `a6`, and two missing non-overlaps `a3` and `a7`. That would give you the digits `012` which would probably be caught by the `012AA` case which does *not* scale.

The letters are not relevant here since there is nothing starting `012` in the special cases that is not `012AA`. So it either doesn't scale because it's not a special case, or it doesn't scale because it's a special case that's specially marked "do not scale".

If you really need scaling in this case, there are apparently other packages that people have suggested may do a better job (such as `Venerable` or `nVennR`). I have no experience with those so cannot recommend them myself but you may want to look into them.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, I tried your suggestion as follows but it didn't create circle on contained value: grid.newpage()
overrideTriple = TRUE
draw.triple.venn(
  area1=2125, area2=805, area3=387, n12 = 805, n23 = 385, n13 = 387, n123 = 385, 
  category=c("#1","#2","#3"),
  col="Black",fill=c("White","Red","Yellow"),
  cex=3, cat.cex=2, euler.d=TRUE, scaled=TRUE)

Comment: @ZamanMuhammadAsad: will post the exact results I get from your values, the circles are scaled but, given the containment properties, they're not a regular-looking Venn.

Comment: Right, added a *great deal* of detail. If I dive any deeper, I'm likely to be crushed by the pressure :-)